# How to deal with iOs keyboard overlapping entry when the page already has a scrollview in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, keyboard, xamarin.forms

I am having a problem regarding the keyboard on iOS. I am developing a chat page on Xamarin, cross platform, and this page has a scrollView which make possible to the user to scroll along the messages.

There is a commom problem regarding the keyboard on iOS, where it covers the entry. iOS doesn't scroll up the page automatically. To solve this problem, a simple solution is to put a tag "Scrollview" covering the whole code of the page. This usually works fine. However, my page already has a scrollview inside it. Therefore, when I put a scrollview inside another scrollview, the behaviour is a little crazy, even on Android. Sometimes it scrolls the "messages view", sometimes it scrolls the whole page.

There is a solution to avoid the keyboard problem on iOS not using the scrollview tag? Or there is a solution to use a scrollview inside another scrollview?

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same problem while trying to implement a chat feature in our app. A solution is to use a custom renderer for the `Entry`, and adjust its margin when the keyboard event is triggered. I followed the pattern [set in this post](http://michaeldimoudis.com/blog/2015/11/14/taming-the-keyboard-in-native-app-development-using-xamarin-forms).

In this case, I embed my `Entry` into a `ContentView`, so I inherit from a `ViewRenderer` to adjust the `ContentView`. Depending on the situation, the Renderer you inherit from may vary. However, in most cases you should be able to reset the margin to the Keyboard's height.

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using HBIClientFacingApp;
using HBIClientFacingApp.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer( typeof(ChatViewWithEntry), typeof(ChatEntryRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class ChatEntryRenderer : ViewRenderer //Depending on your situation, you will need to inherit from a different renderer
    {
        public ChatEntryRenderer()
        {   
            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow ((sender, args) => {

                if (Element != null)
                {
                    Element.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0, args.FrameEnd.Height); //push the entry up to keyboard height when keyboard is activated
                }
            });

            UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide ((sender, args) => {

                if (Element != null)
                {
                       Element.Margin = new Thickness(0); //set the margins to zero when keyboard is dismissed
                }

            }); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do we trigger the Send action when the keybord's Done button is pressed?

Comment: This worked perfect for me after trying all of the other solutions.

Answer (score 8):

One way you can deal with this is a [custom page renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/) that scrolls the whole page up when the keyboard appears.

Here is some sample code to do this. I assume you would only want to do this on pages that have that need it, so first in the Forms PCL (Portable Class Library) project create an empty subclass of `ContentPage` e.g. called `KeyboardInputContentPage` (or whatever you like):

```
public class KeyboardInputContentPage : ContentPage {}
```

Then you inherit from the `KeyboardInputContentPage` for the actual page(s) that you need this functionality, in my test I called it `TestKeyboardInputContentPage`:

```
public partial class TestKeyboardInputContentPage : KeyboardInputContentPage
{ 
    public TestKeyboardInputContentPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //etc
}
```

And the custom page renderer code. This goes in the iOS app project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(KeyboardInputContentPage), typeof(ContentPageRenderer))]
namespace MyAppName.iOS
{
    public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {   
        private NSObject keyBoardWillShow;
        private NSObject keyBoardWillHide;
        private nfloat scrollAmout;
        private double animDuration;
        private UIViewAnimationCurve animCurve;
        private bool keyboardShowing;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            base.ViewDidLoad();

            keyBoardWillShow = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow(KeyboardWillShow);

            keyBoardWillHide = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide(KeyboardWillHide);
        }

        void KeyboardWillShow(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!keyboardShowing)
            {
                keyboardShowing = true;
                animDuration = args.AnimationDuration;
                animCurve = args.AnimationCurve;

                var r = UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(args.Notification);
                scrollAmout = r.Height;
                ScrollTheView(true);
            }
        }

        void KeyboardWillHide(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (keyboardShowing)
            {
                keyboardShowing = false;
                animDuration = args.AnimationDuration;
                animCurve = args.AnimationCurve;

                var r = UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(args.Notification);
                scrollAmout = r.Height;
                ScrollTheView(false);
            }
        }

        private void ScrollTheView(bool scale)
        {
            UIView.BeginAnimations(string.Empty, IntPtr.Zero);
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration(animDuration);
            UIView.SetAnimationCurve(animCurve);

            var frame = View.Frame;

            if (scale)
                frame.Y -= scrollAmout;
            else
                frame.Y += scrollAmout;
            View.Frame = frame;
            UIView.CommitAnimations();
        }
    }
}
```

Since this renderer actually scrolls the entire native page up and back down when the keyboard shows and hides, it should not matter how you layout the page in the Forms Xaml. All that matters is that your Forms page inherits from `KeyboardInputContentPage`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent solution! I am running into a problem though where I type text into an editor and then tap a button to submit that text (see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791511/xamarin-button-command-with-keyboard-open)). It appears this custom renderer is blocking the button from executing the command. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

For iOS you can use this Plugin (add to your iOS project): 
https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap

For Android add following string in MainActivity after LoadApplication(new App());

```
App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().
UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);

// this can also be done by adding WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize as shown below:
 [Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
```

Comment: IOS Part is not working, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516022/xamarin-forms-keyboard-overlap-issue-exist-after-installing-keyboardoverlap-pl
Can you please help?