# Xamarin forms : Keyboard overlap issue exist after installing keyboardoverlap plugin in IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, soft-keyboard

I included the `keyboardoverlap` plugin in IOS project and added `KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init()` after `Xamarin.Forms.Init();` And when I focus Entry, it doesn't move up. I am not using any custom renderer for ContentPage.

**What is the solution for this?**

**Screenshot:**

[image]

My `AppDelegate.cs` Code: Have multiple init codes, is that affect the keyboard overlap feature?

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
 {
    Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init();
    ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App(""));
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with iOs keyboard overlapping entry when the page already has a scrollview in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568100/how-to-deal-with-ios-keyboard-overlapping-entry-when-the-page-already-has-a-scro)

Comment: What is Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(); Why you init it before you call Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init()?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT `Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();` is the init code of popup image. Is there any problem if it added before `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init()`?

Comment: From this link https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap . It seems this package is not support Xamarin.forms 3.x.

Comment: Can you share your sample ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I will provide a sample soon, Meanwhile I will ping you the affected page xaml. his page contain a listview and on the bottom part Editor for sending message. When click on the Editor the keyboard overlapping the editor.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqQr83WMykhee-eQkjb9UaWsIW4